# how to fix Segmentation fault (core dumped) while i use strcat in file operations

Tags: c, string, file

i have written code for storing data in a text file and i have separated my data into 2 strings . and  i did concatenate 2  strings using strcat . but while running its showing segmentation fault(core dumped)..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char *data="867330029590851,144311,140817,130294,0801536,15,00,-1380021593,,N,,,,,180717034311,,,,,4.18,,,,,,,,NA";
    char *timeStamp="14-08-17,14:45:38";

    char *currentTimeStamp=strcat(data,timeStamp);


    /*  open for writing */
    fptr = fopen("RedisData.txt", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File does not exists \n");
        return;
    }
    // printf("string \n");
    // scanf("%s", data);

    printf("%s\n",currentTimeStamp);

    fprintf(fptr,"currentTimeStamp= %s\n",currentTimeStamp);


    fprintf(fptr, "Data    = %s\n", data);
    fprintf(fptr, "TimeStamp     = %s\n", timeStamp);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: `strcat(data,timeStamp)` -> UB detected.

Comment: In C all string literals are *read-only* arrays with only enough size to fit the string and the string terminator. So you are both attempting to write to read-only data, and write out of bounds.

Comment: Find a tutorial on C strings. They are just null terminated char arrays, and like any other array you must never read or write past the end of array...

Comment: Minor: `fclose(fptr);` might not get executed if `fptr` is `NULL`.

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh : how come its duplicate mahn?? just check my code ..? wt else we can do to figure out our errors other than this..this is too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a string literal and any attempt to modify it will invoke undefined behavior.

On the other hand, while using `strcat` there must be enough space in the destination array to hold the source string.

```
char *data="867330029590851,144311,140817,130294,0801536,15,00,-1380021593,,N,,,,,180717034311,,,,,4.18,,,,,,,,NA";
char *timeStamp="14-08-17,14:45:38";
char *currentTimeStamp = malloc(strlen(data) + strlen(timeStamp) + 1);
strcat(currentTimeStamp, data);
strcat(currentTimeStamp, timeStamp);
```

Comment: this one is working for me.                                                                     
char data[500]="867330029590851,144311,140817,130294,0801536,15,00,-1380021593,,N,,,,,180717034311,,,,,4.18,,,,,,,,NA";
    char timeStamp[500]="14-08-17,14-45-38,";

    char currentTimeStamp[500];

     strcat(timeStamp,data);                                   
    printf("%s\n",timeStamp);

Comment: @DeepakVijay; Yes, that will work because  `timeStamp` is now an array of chars and it has enough space to hold `data` string.

Comment: @DeepakVijay : yes it will work and you don't have  to store it in an another variable you can simple use like this..                                               strcat(timeStamp,data);
printf("%s\n",timeStamp);     //this will work for you ...